# Append an array's reverse to itself

Tags: javascript

I have created an array of color values which represents a smooth transition of colors from red to blue.

Now I want this array to take you from red to blue and back again. The obvious solution is to append the reverse of the array to the array.

I have written code to do it, but it isn't working as I understand it should. Instead, it's creating the reversed array, repeated. Instead of "Red to Blue, Blue to Red", it's going "Blue to Red,  Blue To Red".

Clearly, there's some behavior of arrays in javascript that I haven't grasped yet.

What should I be doing?

My first attempt is this:

```
colors = colors.concat(colors.reverse());
```

Based on the first stackoverflow answer, I tried this:

```
var arrayCopy = colors;
arrayCopy.reverse();
colors = colors.concat(arrayCopy);
```

But this produces identical results!

For context, here's the surrounding code:

```
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Creating the array which takes you from Red to Blue
            //
            var colorSteps = 400;
            var startColor = [255, 0, 0];
            var endColor = [0, 127, 255];
            var steps = new Array();
            var j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                steps[j] = (endColor[j] - startColor[j]) / colorSteps;
            }
            var colors = Array();
            for (j = 0; j < colorSteps; ++j) {
                colors[j] = [
                                Math.floor(startColor[0] + steps[0] * j),
                                Math.floor(startColor[1] + steps[1] * j),
                                Math.floor(startColor[2] + steps[2] * j)
                            ];
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Here's the bit where I'm trying to make it a mirror
            // of itself! 
            //
            // It ain't working
            //
            colors = colors.concat(colors.reverse());


            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Demonstrating what the colors are
            //
            j = 0;
            var changeColorFunction = function () {
                if (++j >= colors.length) {
                    j = 0;
                }
                var colorName = "rgb(" + colors[j][0] + ", " + colors[j][1] + ", " + colors[j][2] + ")";
                debugText.style.background = colorName;
                debugText.innerHTML = j;
            }
            setInterval(changeColorFunction, 10);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with:

```
colors = colors.concat(colors.reverse());
```

... is that `colors.reverse()` mutates the `colors` array itself, meaning that you're appending a reversed array to an already-reversed array. Try this instead:

```
colors = colors.concat(colors.slice().reverse());
```

Comment: Oh of course, the method to clone an array is not called "Clone" or "Copy", it's called "Slice". It's so infuriating to learn a new language :-)

Comment: The first use for `slice(start, end)` is not just to clone the array, but to get a "slice" of it, ie a new array containing the items from `start` to `end`. By not passing any argument, you are asking a new array containing the elements from `0` to the end of the array -> a copy of the array itself. This is similar to what happens in Python (where you clone a list using the `[:]` slicing) since "variables" represents pointers, not values, differently from what happens in languages such as PHP.

Comment: If you are interested in digging more about slicing: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Answer (score 3):

Copy your `colors` array to somewhere first. `reverse` changes the array itself, not merely returns a reverted one.

**UPDATE**

Code sample:

```
colors.concat(colors.slice(0).reverse());
```