# Making an independent copy of a reversed array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sepoto/Zgu9J/1/

I'm starting with a reverse function:

```
function reverseArr(input) {
    var ret = new Array;
    for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret.push(input[i]);
    }

    //I tried changing the return value to
    //return ret.slice(0) which has no effect on making
    //an independent copy
    return ret;
}
```

The second array I make pointOrigins2 is not an independent copy of pointOrigins1. In other words modifying pointOrigins2 is also modifying pointOrigins1 which is not what I need to achieve. From my reading on StackOverflow I have tried a few options such as using slice or using a for loop however nothing seems to be working yet so I made a fiddle.

Is there a way to make an independent copy of the reversed array?

Comment: `return input.slice().reverse();`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518616/append-an-arrays-reverse-to-itself

Comment: input.map( (x,i,arr) => arr[arr.length - 1 - i])

Comment: return Array.from(input).reverse();

Comment: This dupe question ended up with better answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610523/reverse-array-in-javascript-without-mutating-original-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a new independent array, but you are not making independent copies of the items that fill your arrays. You need to do something like:

```
function reverseArr(input) {
    var ret = new Array;
    for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret.push({
            positionx: input[i].positionx, 
            positiony: input[i].positiony, 
            index: input[i].index
        });
    }

    return ret;
}
```

so that you are generating new objects (with the same properties) as well as the new array.

Comment: What's the point of cloning the objects when they are not manipulated?

Comment: I don't know, that's just how I'm reading OP's question. His function is making a new array, but modifying the property of an array element would also affect the other array.

Comment: Ah, I see now - he has mentioned that in the fiddle, but not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

use this function

```
function reverseArray(input) {
var newArray = new Array();
for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newArray.push(input[i]);
   }
   return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is clone your array before you reverse it! :)

The shortest way to type is:

```
var b = a.slice();
```

But using concat is correct as well. See:

[Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

If slice does not create a copy for you, you can use numpy arrays and create a deep copy this way:

```
np.copy(a);
```

see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: I had no luck using splice before calling reverseArr.

Comment: Make sure you call your function on the copy created by slice. It should work (if your function works).

Comment: use np.copy(a); if slice doesnt create a copy for you

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working correctly, even if it could be abbreviated to

```
return input.slice().reverse();
```

---

> ```
> //This will show that pointOrigins2 is not an independent copy of pointOrigins1
> //When pointOrigins2 is modified pointOrigins1 is also being modified
> pointOrigins2[0].index++;
> ```

No. You are not modifying the `pointOrigins2` array here, you are only accessing it and modifying *the point* object - the same point that was in the `pointOrigins1` array. Yet, `pointOrigins1 !== pointOrigins2`.

You can modify the array independent from the other, e.g. like

```
pointOrigins2[0] = {
    positionx: pointOrigins2[0].positionx, 
    positiony: pointOrigins2[0].positiony, 
    index:     pointOrigins2[0].index + 1
};
```

and `pointOrigins1` will stay untouched. So if you want to have points whose properties you can modify without being reflected somewhere else, you will need to create new points.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseArr(input) {
    return input.slice().reverse();
}
```

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion? Just use slice to create a copy and then run the copy through your original method. That's the easiest solution by far. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23666706/3570653

Comment: I tried calling slice before calling my original reverseArr. No luck. An independent copy was not created.

Comment: You can create a deep copy of an numpy array then using np.copy(arr): http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html